# How can I generate a .exe from linux? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I have a simple application made ​​in python3, I only have one window and a button, try it with the bdist command:

```
python setup.py bdist --format=zip
```

but not working for me.

with: cx_Freeze

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "guifoo",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("text.py", base=base)])
```

Have any suggestions or recommendations?
a folder is created but I dont see the .exe
If I use images where should I put it?
What about the modules? 
What happens if I use relative paths?

Comment: Why would you create a .exe file in a linux distro? .exe files only work in windows. You can create an executable file in linux, but not a .exe, and especially with Python.

Comment: oh is because I'm programming for Windows but on Linux, assuming that python is multi-platform so I should be able to create multiple executables for different operative systems from my Debian Linux or not?

Comment: @grijalvarmero that is possible indeed.

Comment: Have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired  [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)?


PyInstaller supports cross-compilation:

> Add support for cross-compilation: PyInstaller is now able to build Windows executables when running under Linux. See documentation for more details.

More information [here](http://www.pyinstaller.org/browser/tags/1.4/doc/CHANGES.txt)

Hope this helps :)